# Unity Animation makes object spawn at x0 y0 z0

Tags: unity, animation, coordinates

I was making an animation for a coin in my game in Unity, and when I was testing the full game, I saw that the coin is spawning at `x0` `y0` `z0` and is doing the animation there.
Then I realized that it was the animation, that increases and decreases `y position` and `y rotation`, starting at 0.

So, I need to make the animation, that increases and decreases `position y` and `rotation y`, without affecting the actual position, because it will be different the position of the coins each time.

In a while I will upload a screenshot for describing better the problem.

Any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the animated GameObject inside another GameObject. So for example, you have a prefab named "Coin" with a child inside it named "Coin Mesh" or something like that. Then you can animate the mesh's *local position* within its parent, without it disrupting the coin's world position.

It's also generally a good idea to delete keyframes for properties you aren't using. So for example, when you added the transform position to the animation, it probably created initial keyframes for the X, Y, and Z axes. If you are only animating the coin along the Y-axis, you can delete the keyframes for the X and Z axes so that the animation won't override the GameObject's position along those axes.